# Jackson remove "e" from BigDecimal

Tags: jackson, bigdecimal

I have a low decimal value:  2e-8 
I want it to be presented as JSON in the format 0.00000002

Tried to create a JsonSerializer and use BigDecimal method "toPlainString" but it is not good for me because the JSON has to show a number and not a string value.

What can I do?

Regards, Ido

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The response there is to use the exact method I wrote which is not good for me

Comment: Have you tried to use it as shown (as opposed to how you used it)?

Comment: Yes of course I tried... this is last resort for me

Comment: It would not appear you have tried it exactly as shown, because the result shown there, `{"type":"Int","min":100.0,"max":10200000000}`, seems to be exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I'll try again... thanks

Comment: You are right... I missed something there  Thanks.  Marking this as duplicate